# Using multiple ngrepeat in one html element / or workaround?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I want to make a table like below:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" ng-repeat="item in someitems">{{ item.title }}</th>
      <th colspan="{{ group.items.length }}" ng-repeat="group in some_item_groups">{{ group.title }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="item in (group in some_item_groups).items">{{ item.title }}</th>
    </tr>          
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(I tried to add table pic here but don't have enough reputation points.)

Is there any way to draw this type of table with angular ng-repeat?

Comment: Share your object...!!

Comment: This should work, but I'd have to see your $scope. Can you paste a jsbin or something?

Comment: it seems you can't https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat